# Using onClickListener in Recycler View with Retrofit Structure - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

Hello i have a recyclerview that is filled with some data coming from a Webservice,  using Retrofit.

Now I want to implement a onClickListener, so when i click each row of the Recycler View, i can see more data from that object, and  tried to work with some examples, but i got stucked

Here is my adapter.  I know that in the onCreateViewHolder, i should put in the Return AnunciosViewHolder a second parameter, of the type cellClickListener, but i have no idea what i have to put.   I  tried this@CellCLickListener and this@cellCLickListener and it gave me error that is is unresolved

```
class AnuncioAdapter(val anuncios: List<Anuncio>): RecyclerView.Adapter<AnunciosViewHolder>() {



        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AnunciosViewHolder {

            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerline, parent, false)
            return AnunciosViewHolder(view)
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return anuncios.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AnunciosViewHolder, position: Int) {
            return holder.bind(anuncios[position])
        }


    }
    class AnunciosViewHolder(itemView : View,  private val cellClickListener: CellClickListener): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        private val morada: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.morada)
        private val telemovel: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number)
        private val fotografia: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image)



        fun bind(anuncio: Anuncio) {
            morada.text = anuncio.morada
            telemovel.text = anuncio.telemovel

            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                cellClickListener.onCellClickListener(anuncio)
            }
```

I also tried creating an interface

```
interface CellClickListener {
    fun onCellClickListener (data: Anuncio)
}
```

and in my Activity i put this method  and it gives me an error that «overrides nothing»

```
override fun onCellClickListener(data: Anuncio) {
        val intent = Intent(this@ListaAnuncios, DetalhesActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(PARAM_ID, data.id.toString())
        intent.putExtra(PARAM_MORADA, data.morada)
           intent.putExtra(PARAM_TELEMOVEL, data.telemovel)
        startActivityForResult(intent, newAnuncioActivityRequestCode1)
        Log.e("***ID", data.id.toString())
    }
```

UPDATE

After using the suggestions made by Praveen  i was able to clean my Adapter from errors, however i am struggling in the activity part

if it put

```
val anuncioAdapter = AnuncioAdapter(anuncios, this)
```

on the beggining of my On Create, it doesn't recognize «anuncios»

However i am declaring my adapter inside the call.enqueue

```
 recyclerView.apply {
                            setHasFixedSize(true)
                            layoutManager = 
                             LinearLayoutManager(this@ListaAnuncios)
                            adapter = AnuncioAdapter(response.body()!!)

                        }
```

And it is asking to pass an instance of cellClickListener here, but if i use «this» in here, it is stated that i am trying to pass an instance of the recycler view  instead of the CellClickListener

NEW UPDATE

Forgot to put all the call.enqueue method

```
 call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Anuncio>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Anuncio>>, response: Response<List<Anuncio>>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful){



                      recyclerView.apply {
                            setHasFixedSize(true)
                            layoutManager = 
                           LinearLayoutManager(this@ListaAnuncios)
                            adapter = AnuncioAdapter(response.body()!!)

                        }

                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Anuncio>>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this@ListaAnuncios, "${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }) }
```

i tried both approaches  of @Praveen and @aligur, but still struggling with asking me to put the instance of Clicklistener  as the 2nd parameter,  but using «this» is putting the instance of the Recycler View and not of the ClickListener

Thank You in advance

Comment: `but using «this» is putting the instance of the Recycler View and not of the ClickListener` you can use `this@MainActivity` to select the `activity`'s instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and in my Activity i put this method and it gives me an error that
> «overrides nothing»

You are not implementing `CellClickListener` in your `activity`. Add `CellClickListener` after your `activity`'s class name declaration

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CellClickListener {

}
```

> I know that in the onCreateViewHolder, i should put in the Return
> AnunciosViewHolder a second parameter, of the type cellClickListener,
> but i have no idea what i have to put. I tried this@CellCLickListener
> and this@cellCLickListener and it gave me error that is is unresolved

You've to add the `private val cellClickListener: CellClickListener` parameter to the constructor of `AnuncioAdapter`, not the `ViewHolder`. Only then you will be able to pass it from your `activity`.

Change `constructor` of `AnuncioAdapter` to accept a `CellClickListener` and remove the same from the constructor of `AnunciosViewHolder`

```
class AnuncioAdapter(
    private val anuncios: List<Anuncio>, 
    private val cellClickListener: CellClickListener
): RecyclerView.Adapter<AnunciosViewHolder>() {

}
```

To access this `cellClickListener` inside `AnunciosViewHolder` you've to make it an `inner class` of `AnuncioAdapter`, which you can make, as it's already tightly coupled with the `adapter`.

```
inner class AnunciosViewHolder(itemView : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

}
```

Now, on creating an object of `AnuncioAdapter` inside `activity`, just pass an instance of `cellClickListener` using `this`, as it's already implementing it.

```
val anuncioAdapter = AnuncioAdapter(anuncios, this)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is passing function as parameter to RecyclerViewAdapter.

for instance:

```
RecyclerViewAdapter(val clickListener : () -> Unit)

onCreateViewHolder(){
clickListener.invoke()
}
```

in your view

```
adapter = ReceylerViewAdapter({
//do your stuff here
})
```

Comment: I tried it, but i am getting also the same problem.   I have my adapter inside a call.enqeue  like i put in my new update,  and it is asking me to put the instance of the ClickListener as a 2nd parameter, right after the response.body()!! So i don't know how to do it!   Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Was finally able to find a solution.  By  Using @Praveen suggestion, and by finding this example https://github.com/velmurugan-murugesan/Android-Example/tree/master/RetrofitWithRecyclerviewKotlin/app/src/main/java/app/com/retrofitwithrecyclerviewkotlin

On the activity i added a new val, before the OnCreate method

```
lateinit var anuncioAdapter: AnuncioAdapter
```

Added this on the onCreate (so i could use the first sugestion)

```
val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
        anuncioAdapter = AnuncioAdapter(this,this)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = anuncioAdapter
```

And changed the recyclerview.apply {} on the call.enqeue  just to

```
anuncioAdapter.Anuncios(response.body()!!);
```

And finally created the Anuncios Method on the Adapter

```
fun Anuncios(anuncio: List<Anuncio>){
        this.anuncios = anuncio;
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

With this it works like how i wanted id.  Thanks for the help